# Web Audio API - strange 5.1 behavior

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

I'm trying to play a video file using the js web audio api. Here is the link:

[Sample code](http://anduk.vipserv.org/audio-test/)

When I click the play icon, all channels are playing correctly. But when I click my "Play" button, I have only audio for left and right channels. How can I fix this? My browser is Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

The Web Audio API defaults to 2 channels. You should be able to increase the number of channels by setting audioCtx.destination.channelCount to a higher number.

Comment: Thank you for your answer aldel. Now I have error:

Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to set the 'channelCount' property on 'AudioNode': The channel count provided (6) is outside the range [1, 2].

Any tips?

Comment: Huh, I thought that should work, but it sounds like it's saying it only supports stereo. It might depend on your sound hardware and drivers. Is destination.maxChannelCount 2?